# Is there a way to assert_select an XHR JQuery response in a Rails controller test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller tests, I have assertions like this

```
assert_select "input#name"
```

This works fine for normal HTML requests but it doesn't work with JQuery. The best I've come up with is

```
assert response.body.match /<input .*id=\\\"name\\\".*\/>/
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `assert_select_jquery` to perform `assert_select` on a JQuery response, like this:

```
assert_select_jquery :html, '#content_id .content_class' do
  assert_select "input#name"
end
```

The outer matcher needs to match exactly the JQuery, so the above would match

```
$('#content_id .content_class').html(' ... ')
```

but using only `#content_id` would not.

Comment: Doesn't  work anymore in Rails 6.0 (or probably even before). Any idea on how this could be done?